# Open a New Window using HTML a href hyperlink in WYSIWYG editor

Tags: html, wysiwyg, drupal-8

Can anyone guide me how to open a new window while clicking a hyperlink in Drupal8 editor?
Normally we use window.open() or _target="blank". But in Drupal editor how can I achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below given module for achieve this:

```
https://www.drupal.org/project/editor_advanced_link
```

It Allows to define the following attributes:

- title class id target rel

Comment: Thank you for your response

Comment: I am new to drupal8.could you please explain how to set the title class id target rel to make this done?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open hyperlink in new window you have to use target attribute and the value should be _blank. As I see in your question I think the attribute will be target="_blank"

Thanks.

Comment: I agree with that Asaduzzaman, the question is how to open a new window in Drupal8 editor.